# Redux middleware for dynamic auth / redirecting

Tags: javascript, authentication, reactjs, redux

I attempted to create a very simple redux middleware to handle the auth needs in my application. Users in this app can have 3 states:

- unregistered (should always be redirected to login)
- partially registered (should redirect them to a secondary login. Users need to belong to a group to access any features in the app. So after initial registration they need to create or join a group. OR if they leave their group they'll be in this state and will need to have any actions redirect them to this page until they join a new group)
- fully registered, should have full access with no forced redirects until they log out or leave their group.

So I was thinking a simple solution would be to have middleware that checks the status code of any async actions and redirects accordingly. So maybe a 401 would trigger a redirect to to the login/signup page, `/login`, and a 422 would trigger redirect to the secondary registration, `/register`.

This is my basic set up so far:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

export default function({ dispatch }) {
  return next => action => {
    const url = window.location.href.split('/')
    const location = url[url.length - 1]

    if (location === 'login' || location === 'registration') {
      return next(action)
    }

    let status;
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    if (action.payload) {
      status = action.payload.status
    }

    if (status === 401) {
      return browserHistory.push('/login')
    } else if (status === 422) {
      console.log('redirect to registration')
      return browserHistory.push('/register')
    }

    return next(action)
  }
}
```

Obviously this approach does not utilize any higher order components for auth like most react/redux auth examples use. It seems to work OK, but I see a view start to render for a split second before a redirect so it isn't 100% smooth.

Is there a more efficient / simple way to handle this three state auth system? I am using react-router-redux.

Comment: You ever solve this issue?

Comment: not quite @jamesemanon. I've got a different auth set up on another app using higher order components but I haven't gotten this more dynamic routing with middleware working, I think higher order components is probably the way to go for this as well.